# Forcing Django Login Form to take username over 30 characters

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm trying to use emails for usernames, and have got it working almost perfectly. I followed these directions: http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html

The problem is, my login form still is throwing an error that says the username can only be 30 characters. I've changed the input form to accept 75 chars and the database table to as well. But something in Django is still blocking this.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
<form method="post" action="." class="full">
{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}<li>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</li>{% endif %}
    <li>
        {{ form.username.errors }}
        <label for="id_username">Email/Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="id_username" name="username" maxlength="75">
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ form.password.errors }}
        <label for="id_password">{{ form.password.label }}</label>
        {{ form.password }}
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset %}">Forgot your password?</a>
</form>
```

Comment: @Brenden: What exactly is in the revised `Form` you're using?  Please **update** the question to include the Form class.  Is there a `clean` method which will truncate long inputs?

Comment: Just to check, did you change the field length of username in django.contrib.auth.models.User from 30 to 75, then drop the old auth table from the db, grab fresh SQL to create the auth table by running manage.py sqlall, and execute this SQL to create the new table with the updated field length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I fixed this by adding this to my top level **init**

```
# Added so the login field can take email addresses longer than 30 characters
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

AuthenticationForm.base_fields['username'].max_length = 150
AuthenticationForm.base_fields['username'].widget.attrs['maxlength'] = 150
AuthenticationForm.base_fields['username'].validators[0].limit_value = 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, did you change the field length of username in django.contrib.auth.models.User from 30 to 75, then drop the old auth table from the db, grab fresh SQL to create the auth table by running manage.py sqlall, and execute this SQL to create the new table with the updated field length?

(Since this is just a follow up question, I'd leave it in a comment but don't have quite enough rep yet...)

Comment: I think the missing step is changing the user from 30 to 75 in the django.contrib.auth.models .. Where would I put code that will do that without needing to touch the actual django code?